# req.params.userId not found ( path set to /:userId) Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get an user by his *userId* parameter but it doesn't work. The app connects to the database(Atlas), I can create users, retrieve them all in bulk but I can't retrieve them with a specific parameter ( in this case UserId), producing a not found error message.

**UserRoutes.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const UserModel = require('../models/UserModel');
const app = express();

app.get('/getusersById/:userId', async (req, res) => {

const user = await UserModel.find(req.params.userId);

try {
res.send(user);
} catch (err) {
res.status(500).send(err);
}
});
```

**UserModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Define Schema
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
type: String,
required: true,
trim: true,
},

age: {
    type:Number,
    required:true
  },

userId: {
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
});


//
const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

**Server.js**

```
// Open connection to test database

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserRouter = require('./routes/UserRoutes.js');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const uri = "mongodb+srv://XXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXeXXXX.gcp.mongodb.net/dbusers?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(uri,{
userNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true
});

// Notify if connection was succesful

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on ('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
db.once('open', function() {

console.log("Connection Succesful");

});
db.on('close', () => {
db.removeAllListeners();
});

// Router & Port

app.use(UserRouter);
app.listen(3000,
() => {console.log('Server is running...')});
```

And this is the postman request:

[Postman get userId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqX36.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is wrong. You defined your path as:

```
app.get('/getusersById/:userId', /* callback */)
```

So the request URL should be:

```
/getusersById/3
```

and not

```
/getusersById/?userId=3
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I still can't retrieve the user from the database. When I make a normal request in postman with /getusersById/3 it's hanging, when I make a raw JSON request with { "userId" : "3"} it returns "cannot get /getusersById/". Is it a matter of dependencies in the server.js file? JsParser or UrlEncoded? Thanks

Comment: The correct URL is `/getusersById/3`. If the server hangs it means that it's processing something. Look into your console to see any errors. From what I can see, you have a bug in calling `UserModel.find`, it should be like this: `UserModel.find({ userId: req.params.userId });`

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, it looks like adding"userId:" to req.params.userId solved the issue! I could retrieve Goldorak from my database !

Answer (score 1):

I think you are new to API development. From the image that I can see that you are sending userId as a query parameter. But in code, you are doing `req.parms.userId` which is used for path params. In your code you defined route for path parameter so the request should be like this:

```
/getusersById/3
```

And to be handled as below

```
 app.get('/getusersById/:userId', async (req, res) => {
 const user = await UserModel.find(req.params.userId );
```

However, If you want to pass userId in query parameter then do this:

```
app.get('/getusersById', ...)
```

request can be made like this:

```
/getusersById/?userId=3
```

and query parameter will be accessible as below:

```
 app.get('/getusersById', async (req, res) => {
 const user = await UserModel.find(req.query.userId );
```

[Read this: Query vs Path params](https://medium.com/@fullsour/when-should-you-use-path-variable-and-query-parameter-a346790e8a6d)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sandeep for clarifying this :) I did came accross some of these topics but got a little bit confuse. Yes, I started node.js a week ago, I'll check the sources you both shared. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

```
'/getusersById/:userId'
```

What you are doing here is parameters of your request, which is `userId`

the correct usage of this api is `/getusersById/3`

```
app.get('/getusersById/:usersId', async (req, res) => {

const user = await UserModel.find(req.params.usersId );
```

---

However it seems you want to use `?usersId=3` for query the user id

You need to use `req.query.usersId`

```
app.get('/getusersById', async (req, res) => {

const user = await UserModel.find(req.query.usersId );
```

You can find examples of query usage : https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/handle-get-request-query-string-parameters-in-express-js

Comment: That article clarifies a doubt I had, thanks. I indeed got confused between using req.params or req.query depending on the situation.